# Treeview Event Handling ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview with three Nodes, All I want is to attach EVent Handling functionality to only two nodes the third node will be there for representational purpose only.

Comment: And what type of events are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add your event to the Treeview and not do anything when it relates to your third node, or you can add events only to the nodes you want events on, either as you create them or after.